# Jenkins HTML Publisher не показывает стили, хотя в CSP они разрешены

Tags: jenkins

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой: мои тесты генерируют html-отчет, который я публикую в Дженкинс при помощи HTML Publisher. HTML прикрепляется к джобе, но стили в нем не применяются. В консоли ошибка:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-THOk1r6rC4+HM3k9+2D9L3LsMds3+2crJ1U6Db9rsEk='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Здесь же видел подобные проблемы, и они решались настройкой этой самой политики, но для меня это решение не сработало. Пробовал в Jenkins.xml в аргументах писать `...style-src 'usafe-inline'... и вообще отключать политику, оставляя параметр пустым. Соответствующие изменения отображаются на странице информации о системе,
[image: скриншот параметра со страницы информации о системе] но ошибка в консоли все равно остается такая же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на [баг](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33383) в дженкинсе. Редактирование jenkins.xml не дает результатов. Пока единственный путь - время от времени задавать параметры политики через консоль.